# Activity Designer and nullable types workflow 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In workflow 4.

Is there a way to specify in the **activity designer** an InArgument that is nullable? like Nullable<Decimal>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Argument type select "Browse for Types ..." and search for Nullable. Once you select it prompts you for the type of T and search for Decimal.